How to specify file with spaces in the name using WITADMIN EXPORTWITD
I'm trying to export the "Change Request.xml" file from our project collection using the following command:
It doesn't seem to recognize the filename due to the space in the name. I tried putting double quotes around the path but it still doesn't recognize the name.
Tried the following command:
witadmin exportwitd /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection /p:ProjectName/f:C:\temp\Change Request.xml /n:Change

It doesn't seem to recognize the filename due to the space in the name. I tried putting double quotes around the path but it still doesn't recognize the name.
